# ASP.Net Class References a Control from ASPX Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, class, controls

So, I've seen many discussions that are in this area, but it seems like they are mostly discussing Windows Forms, or they don't get around to answering this specific scenario enough to point me in the right direction.

Exactly what I need to do (Generic Example):

HTML (fragment.aspx)

```
<div id="html_fragment_1" runat="server">Contents</div>
<div id="html_fragment_2" runat="server">Contents</div>
...
```

Code Behind (fragment.aspx.cs)

```
Fragments fragment = new Fragments();
fragment.return_fragment(  AN INSTANCE THAT REFERS TO html_fragment_N  );
```

Class (Fragments.cs)

```
public void return_fragment ( AN INSTANCE THAT REFERS TO html_fragment_N ) {
    string html = INSTANCE.html_fragment_N;
    // DO SOMETHING WITH html
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(html);
}
```

The reason I need to do this is that every aspx form on my site needs to be manipulated in the same way by Fragments.return_fragment(), where the content for several DIVs need to be read from the Form and arranged into an XElement to be returned.

Instead of doing the manipulation in the CodeBehind for every page, I'd rather have each Form use Fragments.return_fragment() so that it saves effort implementing a new Form page, and the code can be changed easily without having to change it in each Form.

Comment: Are these forms using MasterPages? (I am assuming this is web forms, not MVC). Is this for ALL '<div runat="server" />' elements, or just ones with certain names?

Comment: I think we need more information. Why do this? Is the contents of each div dynamic? why do you want to convert the contents of THAT div into an XElement? It just seems like a bad idea to me... but I can't explain why until you provide more information

Comment: The forms are fragments of HTML to be returned, such as via an AJAX request. They need to be able to be returned as raw html, and/or arranged by content type in XML, for two different scenarios.

Comment: The contents of each div does need the option to be dynamic. Some of the fragments returned have data filled out from a database. In some cases all the content needs to be returned and displayed as html. In other cases content needs to be reused for other purposes, and it's returned in XML so the relevant pieces of the fragment can be used.

Comment: So, you're populating those divs through the code-behind on something like page_load, then using ajax you want to pull the contents of those divs out and send them back to the server, format them as XElements, and return them to the browser? Just to make sure I understand it correctly

Comment: AJAX makes a call with a parameter that states if HTML or XML content is expected to be returned. DIVs are populated on page_load. Based on parameter HTML is returned as normal, or processing through Fragments.return_fragment() occurs and XML is returned.

Comment: Basically I just need to know what "AN INSTANCE THAT REFERENCES html_fragment_N" would look like. And how it would be used to access html_fragment_N via the class.

Comment: one of the issues is that `<div` is an html control, that runs client side, its not an asp.net control. Adding `runat=server` doesnt make it run on the server because its still html with an unknown attribute. You want `<asp:Panel id='FooBar'`. Then you can just pass it by its id.

Comment: However, considering that you want to use it with Ajax, you might consider using `<asp:UpdatePanel`. You can google how to use both.

Comment: Steve: Thank you very much. I hate to think how much longer I would have spent on this without your help. I was able to pass the DIVs as an html control as "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl" to the method in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want your app's **Global.asax** file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2(v=vs.71).aspx

Look at your app's page events here as a place to specify things that should happen on every page request.

Comment: From what I've read this might be great, but I don't have a Global.asax file in my application. The documentation is too vague for me to figure out how to implement it.